# Hypothesis Test for a team suffering back to back losses in a season

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Lets assume that a team plays 50 games in a season and has a probability of 67% to win each individual game and 33% to lose each of these games (Games are Independent). I want to create a hypothesis test to determine whether or not the team will lose back to back games in a season (null is that they don't ever lose back to back games in a season and alternate is that they do lose at least 1 set of back to back games in the season). So I am assuming I would set Ho=0 and H1 > 0 to indicate back to back losses, but then I am a little stumped about setting up the test statistic for this problem.

Then once I solve the hypothesis test, I need to estimate the actual probability that the team will not lose back to back games. At first I thought I could use a confidence interval to do this, but I don't think that will work. What are some ways I can go about doing this?

In addition to this, are there any other ways besides hypothesis tests (or Monte Carlo simulations which I have already done) to go about solving this type of problem? I am essentially just trying to learn various ways to solve these types of problems statistically so your help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are the games independent?  If so, then you can calculate the probability that they never have back to back losses.    Or is it not known whether or not they are dependent?  In that case it might make sense to look at the number of back to back losses and ask whether their frequency is consistent with the hypothesis of dependence.

Comment: Games are independent

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what hypothesis is being tested.  Just compute the probability that the team never has back to back losses.  Granted, that seems like an unpleasant analytic exercise but it is easy to simulate.

Comment: Note:  it's easy to compute the expected number of back to back losses.  Using Linearity of Expectation, we note that each of the first $49$ games is the first game in a pair of consecutive losses with probability $\frac 19$, so the expected number is $\frac {49}9\approx 5.44$

Comment: Ok that makes sense. W.R.T the hypothesis test, is it not possible to then test the hypothesis that back to back losses don't occur at least once in the season? I know the expected number of losses computed above essentially means that we would reject the null however, I would like to (if possible) be able to show the hypothesis to reject or fail to reject the null.

Comment: I simply don't understand what that means.  Sometimes they'll have back to back losses and sometimes they won't.  I just simulated $100$ or so runs and I got one list in which they had no back to back losses, so it is definitely possible.  There's no hypothesis here, there's just probability.

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you are saying. I felt like something was missing for it to be a hypothesis test and my mind just got stuck on trying to do a hypothesis test for some reason. All makes sense now. Thanks for the help.